# Microsoft Azure Cosmos DocumentDB Optimal Read Query Performance

Tags: java, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We have implemented an Azure CosmosDB (MongoDB with SQL API) database in the cloud. Through java, we'd like to generate reports based on the data hiding in the MongoDB. I'm not yet too happy with the performance of my read queries, and I was wondering what can be improved to my current setup.

Like said, I use Java to query the database. I use the Microsoft Azure DocumentDB library to query the database:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Currently, the best performance I have been able to get, was to query around 38.000 documents in memory in around 20 seconds, with 50,000 RU/s configured (local cosmos emulator). I would really like this improved, because we might query millions of documents soon.

I have the feeling that the way we store the data, might not be optimal. Each document now look as follows:

```
{
    "deviceid": "xxx",
    "devicedata": {
        "datetime": "2018-08-28T00:00:02.104Z",
        "sensors": [
            {
                "p_A2": "93095",
                "p_A3": "303883",
                "p_batterycurrent": "4294967.10000",
                "p_batterygauge": "38.27700",
                "p_batteryvoltage": "13.59400",
                ** ... around 200 more key - value pairs ... **
            }
        ]
    },
    "id": "aa5d3cf5-10fa-48dd-a0d2-a536284eddac",
    "_rid": "PtEIANkbMQABAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/PtEIAA==/colls/PtEIANkbMQA=/docs/PtEIANkbMQABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-4040-006a7f2501d4\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1535619672
}
```

A query that we would use a lot, would look as follows:

```
SELECT c.deviceid, 
    c.devicedata.datetime, 
    c.devicedata.sensors[0].p_A2, 
    c.devicedata.sensors[0].p_A3,
    c.devicedata.sensors[0].p_batterycurrent,
    c.devicedata.sensors[0].s_humidity 
FROM c 
WHERE c.deviceid = 'xxx'
    AND c.devicedata.datetime >= '2018-08-28T00:00:00.000Z' 
    AND c.devicedata.datetime < '2018-08-30T00:00:00.000Z' 
order by c.devicedata.datetime desc
```

I cut these queries per deviceId. So per device, I run a thread with this query. This seems to go a lot faster than a single thread with a single query.

Such a query as above would take us around 20 seconds.

I have noticed however, if I only query on the deviceid and devicedata.datetime, the query is done within 2 seconds. It seems that getting the sensor data out of the sensor list is a really tough cookie. If I do a select * (so no filtering on the sensor data), it is also faster than when I let the SQL API filter out the sensors: around 15 seconds.

My question is, what can I do to improve upon this? Is my document list too long? is there any way I can set this up differently? The sensor key value pairs are not fixed, and can differ per device.

Some more technical details:
I have an unlimited collection, partitioned on /deviceid.
I have used the standard index policy of Azure (which is index everything), as well as excluding the sensors from it.

I have tried all the tips as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-java

This is my current Java setup, although I have tried lots of different things:

```
//This piece of code is currently in a seperate thread. There is one thread per deviceId to query
documentClient = new DocumentClient(HOST, MASTER_KEY,
                 ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);

FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions();
options.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);

documentList = documentClient
    .queryDocuments(getAlldataCollection().getSelfLink(), query, options)
    .getQueryIterable().toList();
```

I'm fairly sure MongoDB can query hundreds of thousands of documents within seconds, so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with my current setup.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I am right, you would like to aggregate somehow the records you fetch. Maybe you should reduce the amount of data you would like to fetch from cosmosdb and in order to make this faster, you should move your aggragation to the database side: so I would suggest to create [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming) and do the hard work there, and then fetch the result only. I would do it in this way.

Comment: maybe you dont have to write stored procedure, just do some [aggregations](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/azure-cosmosdb-extends-support-for-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-unique-indexes-and-more/) I am not sure, I played with 'classic' mongodb only.

Comment: Thanks mate, this would indeed be an option for us, but sometimes we don't want to do aggregations, and just show the plain data. I'm wondering if I did everything I could to help performance. The SQL Api doesn't really make things easier I feel like.

Comment: Maybe you have just choosen not the right tool for the job. Maybe [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db) fits better if you would like to export a bigger amount of data, however I don't know whether it has Java API or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot provide a definite solution to your problem, but hopefully give you ideas to get to a solution with desired performance level.

### NoSql a good fit?

First, to get this off the table, are you sure your scenario is a good fit for noSQL? CosmosDB shines when the primary scenario is working with pinpoint data (create, select-by-id, update-by-id, delete-by-id). Yes, it definitely can do limited mass operations and aggregations, but querying millions is pushing it. SQL on the other had is designed to work with large sets of data and is really good in doing aggregations.

Let's assume this design decision was carefully weighted and noSQL is the best fit for unmentioned reasons.

### Debug for hard data

**Don't do performance tests against local cosmosDB emulator**. Don't. That's obviously not the real thing (consider network, storage bandwidth/seek times, system impact), but only emulates it. You could get very misleading results. **Spin up a real test instance**.

First step to debugging your query performance problems would be to **enable [query-execution-metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics)** and see where those 20 seconds are actually spent.

Also, loading 38000 documents most likely will never arrive in single batch, check how many continuation queries are actually made to the cosmosDB server.

Also, **run a profiler** and make sure the bottleneck is really in the CosmosDB. If you are making many continuation calls AND concurrently querying over many devices then that may be a lot happening in client as well, and queries flying on the network. Make sure you are not throttled in client (GC, Http stack, internal locking, connection/thread pools, etc).

### Data/Query design

#### Reduce queried data

If you already know `deviceid`, then don't query for it 38000+ times - that's just ballast.

#### Reduce model object size

> /* around 200 more key - value pairs */

That's a huge object. I would test if splitting it up to smaller objects would help cosmosDB to spend less time internally loading and processing documents. Ex:

```
{
    "p_A2": "93095",
    "p_A3": "303883",
    "battery" : {
        "current": "4294967.10000",
        "gauge": "38.27700",
        "voltage": "13.59400"
    }
   ...
}
```

Not sure how docDB is internally storing the documents (full graph vs subdocuments) but you could test if it makes an impact. The difference of 2s vs 20s is so huge that it hints that it may be relevant.

#### Sensors array?

The query only queries for  the first first measurement set. Is the array necessary? You could test if omitting this level has any performance impact.

#### Data types in model

`battery_current` etc are storing sensor measurement numerical values as longish strings. If they are always numbers, then you could store them as numbers instead and reduce document size in server & client. Client performance would probably impacted more (string = heap allocation). Ex: `"4294967.10000"` is 13 chars = 26B in client (UTF-16).

### App design

Do you really need all those 38000 or millions of documents every time? Consider if you could get by with a subset..

If this is for data movement then consider other options (Data factory, change feed processing) to incrementally transfer measurements. If this is on-request app need then consider loading **smaller timeframes** (= less documents) and **use caching** for past timeframes. If you can, pre-aggregate results before caching. Sensor data of past is most likely not going to change.

As always, **consider your business case for ROI**. Optimization is always possible, but sometimes its more beneficial to adjust a business requirement instead of technical solution.

Comment: Thank you mate. A lot of very useful tips I'm going to try out. Thank you so much for the very long and detailed answer. Going to work with this :-)

Comment: One question, you mention: "If you already know deviceid, then don't query for it 38000+ times - that's just ballast." How can I otherwise filter on deviceId? If I don't filter on it, it will get me data from all devices?

Comment: I meant you should include `deviceid` filter in the `where`-section, but omit this from `select`-clause because your client already knows the value for all rows returned by this query.

Comment: I got it now. That makes sense definitely! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The sensor data is being extracted from the document at runtime. So effectively a string blob is being parsed and processed. You will be charged for the resource consumption required to extract the sensor fields.

When you're running select * the query is just returning the whole blob, so no parsing is required.

When the select includes only fields that have been indexed. There is a very high probability that the query will be satisfied by the index data. Therefore, there is no need to visit the document data.

I would try two things. Include the sensor paths in the index policy. This will increase the probability that the query engine can process the query just by visiting the index structure.

Two, remover the order by, this will further reduce the server side processing.

Comment: To remove the ordey by is actulaly a good idea, I might as well do that Java side, as I'm sure it would be faster. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Using order by forces the query to use the Range-index on datetime and you can reason what this means. If you remove it, it will become undetermined which index is used. Do your math which index has on average higher hit chance.  Sorting in client is "usually" slower than using a pre-ordered index on server.

Comment: CosmosDB uses internal heuristics to make decisions about accessing the index or not. So there is no opportunity to force the optimizer down a certain decision path. Re-locating the sort to the client is just a suggestion for experimenting with. The fact that the predicate and the ordering request target the same field does suggest that data at the leaf-level of the bw-tree will already be order by datetime. I'd be interested in getting some feedback from @RensGroenveld